# Remove leading zeroes from the beginning of a string

Tags: performance, strings, linux, assembly, amd64

I want to remove leading zeroes (for a big integer library I'm currently making) in numbers represented as char arrays.

I chose assembly for speed, but in order to simplify making the algorithm and all, I decided to write it in C first. Here's the algorithm, written in C.

```c
void remove_leading_zeroes(char *number) {
  char *answer = (char *)malloc(strlen(number) + 1);
  bool encounteredNonZero = false;
  size_t ptr = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(number); i++) {
    if (number[i] != '0')
      encounteredNonZero = true;
    if (encounteredNonZero) {
      answer[ptr] = number[i];
      ptr++;
    }
  }
  if (!encounteredNonZero) {
    answer[ptr] = '0';
    ptr++;
  }
  answer[ptr] = 0;
  strcpy(number, answer);
  free(answer);
}
```

Also, just before translating to assembly, I like to rename variables with their register equivalents in assembly. This makes it easier for me to translate. Here's the code for that (again C).

```c
void remove_leading_zeroes(char *rdi) {
  char *rsp = (char *)malloc(strlen(rdi) + 1);
  bool cl = false;
  size_t r8 = 0;
  size_t r9 = 0;
  do {
    if (rdi[r9] != '0')
      cl = true;
    if (cl) {
      rsp[r8] = rdi[r9];
      r8++;
    }
    r9++;
  } while (r9 < strlen(rdi));
  if (!cl) {
    rsp[r8] = '0';
    r8++;
  }
  rsp[r8] = 0;
  r9 = 0;
  do {
    rdi[r9] = rsp[r9];
    r9++;
  } while (r9 < r8);
  rdi[r9] = 0;
  free(rsp);
}
```

And finally, the assembly code I wrote. I'm an amateur, so any suggestions on how to make this faster, or any good practice I missed would be awesome.

```
extern strlen

section .text
global _remove_leading_zeroes
_remove_leading_zeroes:
  ; Input:
  ;   - char *number -> rdi. The result will be stored in the same string.

  ; Registers used:
  ;   - rax
  ;   - rcx
  ;   - rdx
  ;   - r8
  ;   - r9

  push   rbp
  mov    rbp, rsp
  call   strlen
  inc    rax
  sub    rsp, rax
  dec    rax
  xor    cl, cl
  xor    r8, r8
  xor    r9, r9
_remove_leading_zeroes_loop_1:
  cmp    byte [rdi + r9], 48
  jz     _after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_1
  mov    cl, 1
_after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_1:
  test   cl, cl
  jz     _after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_2
  mov    dl, byte [rdi + r9]
  mov    byte [rsp + r8], dl
  inc    r8
_after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_2:
  inc    r9
  cmp    r9, rax
  js     _remove_leading_zeroes_loop_1
  test   cl, cl
  jnz    _after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_3
  mov    byte [rsp + r8], 48
  inc    r8
_after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_3:
  mov    byte [rsp + r8], 0
  xor    r9, r9
_remove_leading_zeroes_loop_2:
  mov    dl, byte [rsp + r9]
  mov    byte [rdi + r9], dl
  inc    r9
  cmp    r9, r8
  js     _remove_leading_zeroes_loop_2
  mov    byte [rdi + r9], 0
  leave
  ret
```

(I use my own strlen function which only modifies rcx)

Comment: Do you really think an amateur is smarter than a compiler on which thousands of experimented people worked on for thousands of hours ? For fast code, write clever speed oriented C code, trying to outsmart the compiler would help only in very specific cases.

Comment: In C, there;s no need to cast the value from `malloc()` - it's a `void*`, which converts implicitly to any pointer type.

Comment: @Puck: On the other hand, one may argue that this is a fairly specific case...

Comment: @TobySpeight it could help to write it out explicitly to keep types straight.

Comment: What problem-size are you optimizing for?  Is the typical number of leading zeros like 10 or more, or hundreds?  Or is it usually only a couple?  And what's a common size of later data to optimize for, like ~4K, or are short strings like under 8 bytes common?   Can you make any assumptions about a 16-byte load (like `movdqu xmm0, [rdi]`) not crossing into the next page, especially an unmapped page?

Comment: Does this even work?  It appears to rely on `strlen` not modifying RDI, but that register is call-clobbered.  ([What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672)).  On Linux/glibc, RDI is probably left pointing to the last aligned cache-line of the string, or something like that.  Also, you have a leading `_` in the function name, but this is supposed to be for Linux.

Comment: @PeterCordes oops, I forgot to mention that I use my own strlen function which only modifies rcx.

Comment: @PeterCordes data's usually pretty huge (around 50-60 leading zeroes).

Comment: "Huge" in performance terms for modern CPUs normally means larger than L3 cache, or even so larger that TLB misses start to be a factor, like a few GiB.  I'd say 50-60 is "small" but "non-tiny".  So yeah, very much making SIMD worth it to find the first non-zero about 16x faster than a scalar loop.  But not worth having a big unrolled loop like glibc strlen or strchr (https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strchr-avx2.S.html) that branches once per 4 vectors from an aligned chunk.  I guess strchr not strlen since you need to handle the case of an all-zero string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For style and formatting, your asm is pretty good except for label names.  [Correctly indented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204902/checking-if-a-number-is-prime-in-nasm-win64-assembly/204965#204965), and some intro comments about register usage.  But missing comments about even the major steps of the algorithm on any of the instructions or labels.

It would also help to leave a blank line after the end of a loop, so it's easier to see that later code isn't going to jump back into it.  It's a good place to put a comment about what invariants are now true, or what the next code does.

As other answers point out, your algorithm is doing *way* too much work, using `malloc`/`free` (and in asm, effectively `alloca`) and copying your data twice, instead of just figuring out how far to `memmove` it.

Beyond that, you have multiple other major and minor implementation details that could be more efficient.

(Important background reading: https://agner.org/optimize/ has lots of important micro-optimization stuff, some of which I'm going to point out specifically.  If you don't know what micro-uops (uops) are, go read Agner's asm optimization guide and micro-architecture guide.  Also [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca) and/or some of the links from my answer.  Also a good idea to use compiler-generated asm as a starting-point for your hand-written asm, because compilers generally get the small details right, and might lay out the branching nicely.  (If not you can try `[[likely]]` somewhere and try again).)

Also, not using SIMD means you can at best check 1 byte at a time, not 16 or 32.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so any string processing like this should be using SIMD unless you expect strings to be tiny, like less than 8 bytes or so.  (Or as a baby-steps learning exercise just to write correct scalar code, not useful for performance.)  With some loop unrolling, scalar could possibly check 2 bytes per clock cycle, but branching on a SIMD compare takes more work.  Still a big speedup available.

You might hope that a good C compiler could optimize simple loops to use SIMD, but unfortunately existing compilers like GCC and clang can only auto-vectorize loops where the trip-count can be computed before the first iteration.  i.e. [not search loops with a data-dependent exit condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118583/auto-vectorization-with-rust)  (ICC can sometimes vectorize search loops, and sometimes even do a decent job at it IIRC.)  So this *is* actually a problem where it does make sense to get your hands dirty and use SIMD intrinsics.  There's little need to hand-write anything in assembly, though, especially for x86 where compilers do a good job with intrinsics.

You might also hope that `repe scasb` would be efficient, but it's not, unfortunately.
Only the unconditional `rep movs` and `rep stos` instructions [have Fast Strings microcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480999/how-can-the-rep-stosb-instruction-execute-faster-than-the-equivalent-loop). (See *[Why is this code using strlen heavily 6.5x slower with GCC optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563598)* for how GCC used to inline an inefficient `strlen` at `-O1` or `-O2` in some cases, vs. my simple example of a 16-byte-at-a-time SSE2 implementation that assumes an aligned buffer.)

#### Use more concise label names, prefer NASM local labels like `.else:`

Asm label names are private to the current file, like `static` function names or goto labels within a function in C.  You don't need to make them globally unique since you're not using `global foo` to export them.

It took me half a minute or so to figure out the naming pattern with labels like `_after_remove_leading_zeroes_if_1` vs. `_remove_leading_zeroes_loop_2`.  The "if" vs. "loop" part is a very small part of the label.  It seems obvious in hindsight once you know where to look, but on reading the code for the first time, my reaction was "what is this mess of mostly-redundant long label names?  Hard to see what jumps where".  Then wondering why are there two different `_2` labels, then finally seeing the if vs. while naming (which also apparently go with `_after_remove...` vs. `_remove...` for no apparent reason since the last label in the function isn't named "after".

Meaningful label names are tricky, so yeah you might sometimes just give up and number them from a common base.

In NASM, `.bar:` following a non-dot label like `foo:` is the same as `foo.bar:`, so it lets you use short label names but still avoid name conflicts with the rest of your file.

So you could have asm like

```
remove_leading_zeroes:      ; in Linux ELF, C names don't get leading underscores
 ...
   je   .no_lz
   ; else fall through

.find_nonzero:
  ...
  jne  .find_nonzero

.strmove:             ; in-place strcpy to fill the gap
  ...
  jne  .strmove

.no_lz:  ; return without copying anything
  ret
```

### Make two loops instead of branching inside loops

```
  do {
    if (rdi[r9] != '0')
      cl = true;
    if (cl) {
      rsp[r8] = rdi[r9];
      r8++;
    }
    r9++;
  } while (r9 < strlen(rdi));
```

This is searching for the first non-`'0'` byte in the input string, and then copying the rest of the string to another buffer.  There's no reason to put those two things into one loop, and force yourself to write asm that branches inside each iteration to figure out what to do that iteration.

It wastes at least one uop every iteration, and one side of the `if` is going to have an extra taken branch every iteration for that phase.  (Taken branches are more expensive for the front-end, since code-fetch isn't contiguous and [branch prediction has to provide a correct prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811901/slow-jmp-instruction) of the new place to fetch from early enough to avoid a bubble.  Also, on Haswell and later, predicted-taken jump uops can only execute on port 6; the other ALU port that can check branch predictions can only handle predicted-not-taken branches.)

There's no upside; it would be more efficient to make a simple search loop, and then `strcpy` (manually implemented or not).  If you need some extra logic to detect the case of an all-zero string, that logic can be outside any loops.  Small static code-size is nice, but fewer instructions inside loops is usually more important.

I think the simplest way to handle the possibility of an input like `"0000"` or the empty string is to copy the first byte unconditionally, before doing anything else.  That also lets the CPU get started on getting write access to the output buffer, in case it was cold in cache or TLB, letting out-of-order exec hide latency.  Normally not a factor for stack space, it's usually hot in cache.  (If you can't allocate the output buffer until after reading all of the input to calculate the size, that's unfortunate.  Depending on your allocator, over-allocating and then using realloc to give back a chunk at the end might be ok.)

Of course this problem goes away when you're doing it in-place, not copying to a separate buffer.  Once you make that other algorithmic change, you can't use ISO C `strcpy` since it [has undefined behaviour if the src and dst overlap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).  So you would need to hand-roll your copy loop for that in asm, or in C use `strlen` and `memmove`, or intrinsics like `_mm_cmpeq_epi8`.  Pure ISO C doesn't give you the building blocks you need to make an efficient version of this function, given limitations of current compilers, so the best you can portably do in C is glue together hand-written asm building blocks like `strlen` and `memmove`, even though that makes two passes over the data.

(Perhaps cache-block it in 16KiB chunks with `memchr` instead of `strlen`, so you stop after 16K and can memmove while that part of the data is still hot in L1d cache.)

In asm you *can* potentially do as well as the hand-written libc code, most simply by using a copy of it.  https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S.html shows a version of glibc's `strlen`; with minor changes you could adapt it or `memchr` to look for a *non*-match of `'0'`.  (That would cover finding the terminating `0` byte).  Or pick any other asm strlen or memchr you want.  Most should be safe for the case where `dst` is at a lower address than `src`: reads will happen before writes so it should be reading pristine data.

Depending on the input buffer, you might also have to worry about alignment, e.g. a 2 byte string in the last 2 bytes of a page, followed by an unmapped page.  A 16-byte load would segfault.  (Or if the next page is mapped, still be expensive, worst case even paging it in from disk if it didn't otherwise need to be touched.)  See [*Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64) - an *aligned* 16 or 32-byte load can never be split across a wider alignment boundary like 4k.  So if your input buffer is always aligned, or always at least 32 bytes allocated, this is trivial: do the first 16-byte vector unaligned, then do `(p + 32) & -32` and stay aligned from there.

---

## Micro-optimizations

Some of these instructions are ones you won't need after algorithmic changes, but in other functions you might still want to do something similar.  Some of them will still be needed in different forms.

#### Prefer pointer-increments over indexed addressing modes

`cmp    byte [rdi + r9], 48` / `jz` will decode to 3 uops for the front-end on Intel Skylake CPUs.  Micro-fusion is [defeated by the indexed addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) (2 registers), and macro-fusion of the cmp/jnz doesn't happen with `cmp mem,imm`  (See [*What is instruction fusion in contemporary x86 processors?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413517/what-is-instruction-fusion-in-contemporary-x86-processors)).

This also saves registers; you just need an input and an output pointer.  (And an end-pointer or a down-counter).

The loop structure should be something like `for(char *p = start, *endp = start+len ; p<endp ; p++) { stuff with *p; }`.  But of course [in a `do{}while()` style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump) like you're doing, with the conditional branch at the bottom.  That's a very Good Thing.  Generating `endp = start+len` just takes an LEA, and then the bottom of the loop is still a `cmp`/`jne` or `jb`.  Otherwise you might use `dec ecx`/`jnz` or whatever for a loop like `do{ p++ }while(--len);`.  Intel CPUs can macro-fuse dec/jnz, but AMD CPUs can only macro-fuse CMP or TEST.  So it can save a uop inside the loop to do a pointer compare, at the cost of needing an LEA at the start.

Of course this only applies to counted loops in the first place, and after the algorithmic changes you wouldn't have those, just search loops.  But you'd still have pointers that you increment, first read-only for the first non-`'0'`, then from there and from the start to copy, checking for a terminating `0`.

In a loop where you're going to want that byte in a register later (to store), **you should just load it into a register now and test it there.**

```
  movzx  eax, byte [rdi]    ; 1 uop, no false dependency on the old RAX
  cmp    al, '0'            ;   macro-fused with jnz
  jnz                       ; 1 uop
; 2 total uops for the front-end, 2 for the back-end.
```

(**Write ASCII characters as character literals like `'0'`, not `48`**)

Also, **use `jb` or `ja` for comparing pointers, or `jl`/`jg` for comparing signed integers**.  You did

```
 cmp    r9, r8
  js   ...
```

This is different from `jl` if the subtraction has signed overflow.  That's normally not going to be a problem with 64-bit integers that work as offsets to an address, because the middle of the address space (around the signed-overflow wrapping point) is non-canonical.  See [*Should pointer comparisons be signed or unsigned in 64-bit x86?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687805/should-pointer-comparisons-be-signed-or-unsigned-in-64-bit-x86)

For performance, **[`js` won't macro-fuse with `cmp` on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771526/x86-64-assembly-loop-conditions-and-out-of-order), but `jl` and `jb` will.**

Also, for human readers, jumping on less-than has the right semantic meaning of `do{}while(r9<r8)` like you wrote in your C source.  Jumping if the subtraction result is negative (after wrapping) does not.

---

#### Use `movzx` for byte loads, especially in loops

`movzx` avoids false dependencies on CPUs more recent than Nehalem and first-generation Sandybridge.  See [*Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers).

Similarly, `mov ecx, 1` or `xor ecx,ecx` for a boolean. Don't write partial registers if you don't need to.

In fact, **always xor-zero with 32-bit operand-size**, even for registers that need a REX prefix to access, because early Silvermont CPUs *only* recognize `xor r8d,r8d` as a zeroing idiom, not `xor r8,r8`.  See details in [*What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)

---

```
  inc    rax
  sub    rsp, rax
  dec    rax
```

Normally you'd want to keep the stack aligned by 16, and there's no need to change RAX when you want that value later; you could add into a different register.

```
  lea  rcx, [rax+1 + 15]    ; rax+1  for the extra byte, and +15 as part of (x+15)&-16 to round up to the next multiple of 16
  and  rcx, -16
  sub  rsp, rcx             ; alignas(16) char buf[rax+1]
```

To save code-size, if your string will always be less than 4GiB you can use `ecx` for LEA and AND (32-bit operand-size is the default in x86-64 machine code with no prefixes).  On a CPU without partial-register stalls, `and cl, -16` would also work efficiently, since the only bits you're clearing are in the low byte so it works to leave the rest unmodified.  Same as `and rcx, -16` but without needing a REX prefix.

---

```
  push   rbp
  mov    rbp, rsp
  ...
  leave
```

That is useful if you variably modify RSP.  Otherwise don't do it.  Once you fix the algorithm, there's no need to touch stack space.

Comment: (This answer is a bit disorganized because there's so many different things to point out here, and some of the micro-architecture reasons behind them are subtle.  I've written about them on Stack Overflow so I linked a bunch of those Q&As to explain why something is better.)

Comment: Thank you! Finally, an answer which actually reviews the assembly code. I just put the C code there so it was easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

#### C doesn't match assembly

> ```
>   for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(number); i++) {
> ```

You don't seem to actually be doing this.  Your actual assembly is more like

```
  for (size_t i = 0, n = strlen(number); i < n; i++) {
```

Which is good, as there is no reason to call `strlen` on each iteration.

#### Could be simpler

This seems more complicated than it needs to be.  Consider

```
    char *answer = number;
    while ('0' == *answer) {
        ++answer;
    }

    if (answer == number) {
        return;
    }

    memmove(number, answer, strlen(answer) + 1);
```

At the end of this, we know the location of the first non-zero or the null.  If we never incremented `answer`, we know that there were no leading zeroes.  Therefore, we don't have to `malloc` or copy.  No `malloc` means no need to `free`.  We can also do without `encounteredNonZero` and `ptr`.

We also don't need to check if we are at the null byte.  The null byte is not `'0'`, so we can check only for `'0'`.  The null byte and non-zero digits get caught by the same check.

We only need to check if we incremented.  If we did, we found at least one leading zero and need to move the string.  If we didn't, we're done.  We don't need to do anything.  The original string was already correct.

The [`memmove`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) does not require an intermediate variable.  We can call it directly and let it worry about the overlap.

It's not clear to me if converting this version to assembly is necessary.  It may be that the assembly the compiler produces is already optimized as much as it can be.  In particular, I would expect `memmove` to be more optimized than its manual replacement on most architectures.  If you want, you could change the `memmove` to

```
    while (*answer) {
        *number = *answer;
        ++number;
        ++answer;
    }
    *number = 0;
```

Then see if you can optimize that in assembly.  But as I said, I suspect that the compiler on most architectures will already do this for you.  Or do something better.

There are some assumptions that this makes that the compiler might not.  For example, this assumes that `answer > number`.  This makes sense in this code, as we only increment `answer`, it starts as `number`, and we explicitly checked if they were equal.  A compiler might start its `memmove` by checking if `answer` and `number` are equal, less than, or greater than.  Because the logic is different for those three cases.

#### Consider alternatives

For example:

```
char *remove_leading_zeroes(char *number) {
    while ('0' == *number) {
        ++number;
    }

    return number;
}
```

This has a different signature, returning a string rather than modifying the input string.  You would use this differently.  You wouldn't be able to `free` what this returns.  You'd have to keep the original separate so you could free that.

The advantage of this form is that it doesn't move/copy the string.  The disadvantage is that you have to track two variables:  one to `free` and one to use.  Yes, sometimes they are the same, but you can't rely on that.  Sometimes they are different.

If you hold on to the original function signature, then obviously this won't work.  This is meant to be used in a different fashion.  It is less generally applicable.  But without any memory allocations or copies, it should be very fast.  If you find speed important enough that you are optimizing into assembly, then rewriting your calling code to work with this would likely be easier.  And faster, even without converting into assembly.

Comment: Writing in assembly lets you make maximum use of SIMD, like `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb` / `not` / `tzcnt` to find the position of the first non-`'0'` byte, i.e. the special case of `strspn` with a 1-byte "accept" string.  If you're not going to do that, then yes it's probably best to just look at compiler-generate asm.  Of course, you can manually vectorize with intrinsics in C, and let the compiler take care of things like `xor ecx,ecx` as being more efficient than `xor cl,cl` (false dependency on the full RCX).

Comment: (Of course you have to beware of [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) depending on how you allocated the buffer you pass to this function.  Hand-writing asm has the minor advantage of completely hiding undefined behaviour from a C compiler; reading outside the bounds of an array (even if you don't cross into another page) is still technically UB.)

Comment: And BTW, no, neither GCC nor clang will optimize a C version well.  You might well get something better than the hand-written asm because it's full of partial-register false dependencies and stuff, but [only ICC knows how to auto-vectorize a loop with a data-dependent exit condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118583/auto-vectorization-with-rust).  (Like a search loop).  So pure C isn't going to get you optimal code which handles 16 or 32 bytes at a time.  Or 8 bytes at a time if the leading-zero range is often short, like a qword load + xor with `'00000000'`, then `tzcnt`.

Comment: But anyway, +1 for good points about the C version being way over-complicated.  Yeah, just in-place memmove is the obvious thing, or (if C compilers could optimize decently), a manual loop that copies until seeing a `0` byte so you don't need a `strlen` to start with.  Or if `strcpy` was safe to use on overlapping input/output...

Answer (score 6):

Choosing assembly for speed is likely an error.  You will have to spend a lot of time optimising for your hardware to beat a well-tuned compiler¹.  And you'll need to repeat that every time you target a new processor.

I'm disappointed to see no unit tests for the function.  Never write assembly code without tests!

We are missing the necessary check whether `malloc()` returned null or a valid pointer.  Luckily, allocation is not required, as [mdfst13's answer](/a/279640/75307) shows.

If we write in C, we can benefit from compiler optimisations, including function inlining.  We can give our compiler an opportunity to improve the `memmove()` by providing an `assert()` so that it can be sure we're moving from higher to lower addresses.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_leading_zeroes(char *number)
{
    const char *answer = number;
    while (*answer == '0') {
        ++answer;
    }

    if (answer == number) {
        /* no leading zeros */
        return;
    }

    assert(answer > number);

    /* include the terminating NUL character */
    memmove(number, answer, strlen(answer) + 1);
}
```

We might find our requirements change.  Perhaps users expect an input that's all zeros to result in a single zero (usually, we denote 0 thus, not as empty string).  That's easy to arrange in the C code:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_leading_zeroes(char *number)
{
    const char *answer = number;
    while (*answer == '0') {
        ++answer;
    }

    if (!*answer && answer > number) {
        /* all zeros; retain the last one */
        --answer;
    }

    if (answer == number) {
        /* no zeros to remove */
        return;
    }

    assert(answer > number);

    /* include the terminating NUL character */
    memmove(number, answer, strlen(answer) + 1);
}
```

If we write assembly, then we'd need to re-optimise for all our target platforms after making such a change.  It's a better use of our time to let our compiler do that for us.

---

¹ Unfortunately, which I tried `gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native`, it didn't inline or optimise the library functions here.  Perhaps you should consider that a cue to direct your skills to improving their code generation *for all programs*, rather than resorting to manual assembly code to bypass the issue.

Comment: *You will have to spend a lot of time optimising for your hardware to beat a well-tuned compiler such as `gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native`* - Only if you know the limitations of GCC's optimizer and work around them, or manually vectorize with intrinsics.  [Only ICC knows how to auto-vectorize a search loop with a data-dependent exit condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118583/auto-vectorization-with-rust).  For non-tiny numbers of leading zeros, it's quite easy to beat your pure C version which will compile to asm that checks 1 byte at a time, using SSE2 or just scalar xor/bsf.

Comment: Unfortunately the C standard library doesn't expose the opposite of `strchr`, looking for the first non-match, only `strspn` which takes a set of chars to match, so the library would have to special-case a set-size of 1 to use a version vectorized the way `strchr` is (https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S.html).  I don't think glibc does that, instead always building an accept/reject map to check 1 char at a time.  (i386 has hand-written asm, https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/i386/strspn.S.html, x86-64 just uses the portable `.c`)

Comment: This will compile to a better implementation than the OP's asm.  (And would have been a good algorithmic starting point, and the compiler-generated asm would have been a good  implementation starting point.)  But for leading zero counts higher than maybe 6 to 12, it would really fall behind.

Comment: Also, 2 passes over the string (strlen + memmove) sucks vs. an in-place `strcpy` which you can write by hand in asm, using an implementation like glibc's.  Of course you have to be using at least SSE2 instructions, preferably AVX2, not just scalar to get big speedups.  ISO C doesn't give you efficient building blocks for this.  Although in many cases you could redesign the API to take a pointer+length so there's no need to search for a terminating `0` byte, and that would also remove a tricky problem to handle from the initial `memchr` in terms of reading past the end of a possibly-small array

Comment: BTW, you suggested that it would be nice for GCC to inline these library functions.  That would remove the possibility of dynamic dispatching based on the CPU, to use an AVX2 `strlen` and `memmove` on CPUs that support it.  (Or even AVX-512BW using 256-bit vectors, since masking is quite useful for handling odd sizes.)

Comment: See also [Why is this code using strlen heavily 6.5x slower with GCC optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55563598) - GCC *used* to inline `strlen` inefficiently, even worse than a simple SSE2 version, especially at `-O1`.  It's a tough tradeoff esp. w/out `-march=native`, since a simple inline version could be faster for small strings, but fall behind over larger strings like a few KiB, especially if they're hot in L1d cache.  (A good strlen can almost keep up with L2 bandwidth but maybe only with some unrolling, and certainly L3 bandwidth for a simple version without AVX2).

Comment: All good points @PeterCordes (and a worthwhile hint to OP to use compiler for a good starting point for optimising the assembly - perhaps even write partly in C and partly in compiler intrinsics or inline assembly).  I see there's a chicken-and-egg problem with `strlen()` and `strcpy()` - we don't know which implementation is best until we know the length of the string!  Unless we have good _a priori_ knowledge of the likely inputs, we might need to learn from usage (a bit like like branch prediction in CPUs), but it's likely that the overhead of measurement would outweigh the benefit.

Comment: In the all-zero case, why not just `number[1] = '\0'; return;`?

Comment: Good suggestion @Roger!  We still need the test that excludes `""` input, so we know `number[1]` is valid at that point.

Comment: Wrote up an answer with most of what I suggested in comments before.  Also with an actual review of the asm itself.  I could delete some of those earlier comments if they're too cluttered, but most of them are relevant to suggestions this answer makes.