# A Simple C Program to Find Factors of any Integer

Tags: beginner, c, factors

I have written a simple CLI app that finds factors in 3 different forms. I would like the code to be reviewed.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void eq(int num)
{
    int factor_found = 0, factor = 2;
    printf("%d = " , num);

    while(factor_found==0)
    {
        if(num%factor==0 && num!=0)
        {
            printf("%d*" , factor);
            num = num/factor;
        }
        else if(num==-1 || num==0 || num==1)
        {
            printf("%d." , num);
            factor_found=1;
        }
        else
        {
            ++factor;
        }
    }
}

void n(int num)
{
    int factor_found = 0, factor = 2;
    printf("Factors of %d are : ", num);

    if(num==1 || num==-1)
    {
        printf("%d,%d.", num, num*-1);
    }
    else if(num==0)
    {
        printf("Math Error.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("1, -1, ");
        while(factor_found==0)
        {
            if(num%factor==0 && num!=factor && num!=factor*(-1))
            {
                printf("%d, %d, ", factor, (factor*(-1)));
                ++factor;
            }
            else if(num==factor || num==factor*(-1))
            {
                printf("%d, %d.", num, (num*(-1)));
                ++factor_found;
            }
            else
            {
                ++factor;
            }
        }
    }
}

void poc(int num)
{
    int factor_found = 0, factor = 2, no_of_factors = 0, temp;
    if(num==1 || num==0 || num==-1)
    {
        printf("%d is nor prime nor composite.", num);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = num;
        num = abs(num);
        while(factor_found==0)
        {
            if(num%factor==0 && num!=factor)
            {
                ++no_of_factors;
                num=num/factor;
            }
            else if(num%factor==0 && (num==factor || factor==1))
            {
                num=num/factor;
            }
            else if(num==1 || num==-1)
            {
                ++factor_found;
            }
            else
            {
                ++factor;
            }
        }

        if(no_of_factors==0)
        {
            printf("%d is a prime number.", temp);
        }
        else if(no_of_factors!=0)
        {
            printf("%d is a composite number.", temp);
        }
    }
}

void check(char mode[5], int num)
{
    if(strcmp(mode, "-eq")==0 || strcmp(mode, "eq")==0)
        eq(num);
    else if(strcmp(mode, "-n")==0 || strcmp(mode, "n")==0)
        n(num);
    else if(strcmp(mode, "-poc")==0 || strcmp(mode, "poc")==0)
        poc(num);
    else if(strcmp(mode, "-all")==0 || strcmp(mode, "all")==0)
    {
        eq(num); printf("\n");
        n(num); printf("\n");
        poc(num);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid Argument!");
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = atoi(argv[1]); char mode[5];

    if(argc==1)
    {
        printf("Enter the number : ");
        scanf("%d" , &num);
        printf("Enter the mode : ");
        scanf("%s" , mode);
        check(mode, num);
    }
    else if(argc==2)
    {
        printf("Enter the mode : ");
        scanf("%s" , mode);
        check(mode, num);
    }
    else
        check(argv[2], num);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`conio` is not a portable library so you should not rely on it.

You should include `stdbool.h` and represent `factor_found` as a `bool`. However, in all cases, use of this flag is uncalled-for and you should simply `break`.

In all cases, your use of `while` is better-represented by `for`.

All of your functions other than `main` should be `static`.

`num==-1 || num==0 || num==1` should be reduced to two inequality comparisons.

`n` as a function needs a better name. I don't know what that does unless I read the whole source.

`factor*(-1)` should just be `-factor`.

`main` should always return `int`.

If the user does not pass any arguments, we expect `atoi(argv[1])` to produce a memory fault. If it doesn't, that's entirely by coincidence: welcome to C.

`atoi` is not a safe function because it cannot tell you whether user input is valid or not. Prefer instead something like `strtol`, and either bounds-check and cast back to an `int`, or (more easily) use `long` throughout.

You should be compiling against the C17 standard, and using its features where appropriate, especially moving variable declaration away from the function start and closer to use.

Whenever you print an error, you should usually print to `stderr` and not `stdout`.

`temp` is not a good variable name. In this case, prefer something like `orig_num`.

The responsibility for printing terminating newlines should be moved into your individual functions.

Factors `"%d, %d, ", factor, (factor*(-1)));` have a slightly wobbly definition. See [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor); some definitions expect that only positive divisors are shown.

`check` should not accept a `char` array, since it should work with any string length; instead accept `const char *`.

Reduce repetition in `main` by only accepting the `mode` string once.

### Suggested

I believe this to be equivalent but you should verify. This has been compiled with the following `makefile`:

```
282213: main.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

main.o: main.c
    gcc -o $@ $^ -c -Wall -std=c17
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


static void eq(long num)
{
    printf("%ld = ", num);

    for (int factor = 2;;)
    {
        if (num >= -1 && num <= 1)
        {
            printf("%ld." , num);
            break;
        }
        if (num%factor==0)
        {
            printf("%d*", factor);
            num /= factor;
        }
        else ++factor;
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

static void n(long num)
{
    printf("Factors of %ld are: ", num);

    if (num==1 || num==-1)
        printf("%ld,%ld.", num, -num);
    else if (num==0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Math Error.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("1, -1, ");
        for (long factor = 2;; ++factor)
        {
            if (num==factor || num==-factor)
            {
                printf("%ld, %ld.", num, -num);
                break;
            }
            if (num%factor==0)
                printf("%ld, %ld, ", factor, -factor);
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

static void poc(long num)
{
    if (num >= -1 && num <= 1)
    {
        printf("%ld is nor prime nor composite.\n", num);
        return;
    }

    long orig_num = num;
    int no_of_factors = 0;
    num = labs(num);
    for (long factor = 2;;)
    {
        if (num%factor==0 && num!=factor)
        {
            ++no_of_factors;
            num /= factor;
        }
        else if (num%factor==0 && (num==factor || factor==1))
            num /= factor;
        else if (num==1 || num==-1)
            break;
        else
            ++factor;
    }

    if (no_of_factors==0)
        printf("%ld is a prime number.\n", orig_num);
    else printf("%ld is a composite number.\n", orig_num);
}

static void check(const char *mode, long num)
{
    if (!strcmp(mode, "-eq") || !strcmp(mode, "eq"))
        eq(num);
    else if(!strcmp(mode, "-n") || !strcmp(mode, "n"))
        n(num);
    else if(!strcmp(mode, "-poc") || !strcmp(mode, "poc"))
        poc(num);
    else if(!strcmp(mode, "-all") || !strcmp(mode, "all"))
    {
        eq(num);
        n(num);
        poc(num);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid mode\n");
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char mode_entry[5];
    const char *mode;
    long num;
    
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        if (scanf("%ld", &num) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number\n");
            return 1;
        }            
    }
    else
    {
        char *endptr = NULL;
        num = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
        if (endptr == argv[1])
        {
            perror("Invalid number");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Enter the mode (eq|n|poc|all): ");
        if (scanf("%4s", mode_entry) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid mode string\n");
            return 2;
        }
        mode = mode_entry;
    }
    else
        mode = argv[2];
    
    check(mode, num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. First of all I have removed `conio.h` as its actually not needed, my bad. Secondly, I usually prefer `if, else if` but if there are any advantages of using switch then please explain. Further the function `n` got its name because it prints all the 'n' numbers which are factors. Next I have 2 questions which is why should the `main` function always return `int`? and how could  I overcome the dangers of `atoi` function. Lastly if the user does not pass any arguments then the if statements in the `main` function are there for backup. All the other suggestions are considered.

Comment: SHUBHAM KULKARNI, "why should the main function always return int" --> `main()` returning `int` is allowed by all compilers.  Returning `void` relies on _implementation-defined_ compiler attributes.

Comment: @SHUBHAMKULKARNI "if the user does not pass any arguments then the if statements in the main function are there for backup" --> Too late.  Those tests needed before attempting to read `argv[1]` in `atoi(argv[1])`.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica for clearing my question and also helping me understand my mistake.

Comment: _the function n got its name because it prints all the 'n' numbers which are factors_ - that's not good enough. 100% of developers, upon seeing such a name out-of-context, would assume that it's a variable and not a function

Comment: Ok, I have changed the function `n` to `n_factors`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am still pretty new to C and what you suggested went over my head, hence a explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Pedantic: `num = labs(num);` risks UB when `num == LONG_MIN`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica also it would be easier if you compiled all your suggestions in your answer by editing it. Thank you.

Comment: @SHUBHAMKULKARNI Please be more specific about what suggestion and what part went over your head.

Comment: @SHUBHAMKULKARNI These comments primarily relate to this answer and so not part of my answer to your code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks; see edits. re. `labs` it's edgy enough that I think I'll leave it as is and preserve your comment.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica nevermind, I have cleared my doubt. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Reinderien also thanks to you for helping me with my code.

Comment: I don't agree with `num >= -1 && num <= 1` being better than `num == -1 || num == 0 || num == 1` in this case.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't contain the `do` keyword or any `do{}while()` loops.  It has some `int var=value; while(){}` loops that should be `for()` or `do{}while()` loops, though!  (Especially if the `do{}while()` let the controlling expression see variables declared inside the loop, it would be great for loops that discover an exit condition instead of having a counter.  But since it doesn't, it's often not that wonderful.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, edited; and I am equally disappointed about `while` loop variable accessibility

Answer (score 5):

**Do not use `scanf("%s"..` without a *width***

Prevent buffer overruns.
Use a width, which limits the characters read, to 1 less than the array count.

```
char mode[5];
// scanf("%s" , mode);
scanf("%4s" , mode);
```

Or to drive the *width* from one place, use the pre-processor `#` operator.
Makes for easier maintenance.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#define MODE_LEN 4
char mode[MODE_LEN + 1];
scanf("%" TOSTRING(MODE_LEN) "s" , mode);
```

Better code would also check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

## Function names

`n` and `eq` are very unclear names, unless they clearly correspond to a referenced formula. `eq` usually stands for "equals" or "equation", and it's not clear what "equals" would do for one input.

## Input handling

I assume you have a consistent way to handle negative numbers. You can simply output -1 as a factor, test for 0, and then only consider positive integers. This would reduce the negative number and zero checks.

## Trial Division Algorithm

I think a for loop testing divisors from 2 to n instead of unbounded incrementing is easier to understand. A simple optimization is to divide out 2s and then odds. In fact, you need to only try dividing out primes. (Why is this true?) In this way, using a sieve to get a list of primes and only trying dividing those will be much faster for large inputs (prime number theorem). By the way, the largest factor to try division is sqrt(n); if n leftover after dividing is not 1 then that is the largest prime factor. (Why is this true?) This cuts down the worst-case number of checks from O(n) to O(sqrt n).

Here is python / pseudocode that factors a number into a dictionary of its prime factorization (similar to sympy's `factorint`):

```py
def factor(n):
    assert n > 0  # only handle positive integer input

    factors = Counter()
    for d in range(2, n):
        if d * d > n: break  # d up to sqrt(n)
        while n % d == 0:
            n //= d
            factors[d] += 1

    if n > 1: 
        factors[n] += 1
    return factors
```

Comment: `if d * d > n` overflows when `n` is a large prime.  Consider `if d > n/d`.

Comment: On many machines, you can get the quotient for basically free while getting the remainder.  That being the case, `n / d <= d` is a cheap way to detect that you've reached `d >= sqrt(n)` without doing a sqrt(n) once or an extra multiply every time.  ([Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965))  Oh right, and as chux mentions, overflow is a possible problem in C, unlike in Python which you've used for this answer.  (`n` can be greater than the largest non-overflowing perfect square)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica true - one of the benefits of working in pypy :)

Comment: qwr, Such benefits come with a cost.  IAC, post is tagged C and deserves C considerations.